# Kubuntu 15.10 | Wine | cannot import dll :isskin.dll

Tags: wine

error in installing game mafia2-black box.

```
cannot import dll :isskin.dll.
```

[image]

Comment: may this helps: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/red-hat-31/wine-runtime-error-isskin-dll-issue-879119/

Comment: thnx buddy....i asked same question on that link, waiting for reply...

Comment: if it does not solve the issue you can still try "playonlinux" - ill check back later on this post - once you have the solution you can answer the question here :)

Comment: i am still waiting for reply on that  LINUXQUESTION.ORG no one reply yet

Comment: Have you tried the proposed solution or playonlinux?  I dont have an option to replicate the issue today, out of office soon. Found this just yet by google query "mafia2 playonlinux" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixFNZYQG4iQ its czech lang but you can follow point n click.

Comment: ya run it with playonlinux and also installed it from playonlinux but not running

Comment: i am very thankful to you to do this for me, its a lot for me, first do your work, and if you find any solution then tell me

Comment: is it working, if yes may write the answer? ill get back tomorrow, going offline for today

Comment: ok, got it, ill check back tomorrow if nobody else drops in

Answer (score 1):

> The error message:    `cannot import dll :isskin.dll` is created
>   through the missing dll library. on a baremetal wine install its
>   installed with winetricks through the console by executing
>   `winetricks vcrun6sp6`.

In playonlinux you can **install libraries** when creating or editing a VM - the library name to install to solve the issue is **vcrun6**.

Same for directX - the game installer of direcX 9c did not work, thus i skipped it on the second try.

The playonlinux library `d3dx9` seemed to work as the game started and i was able to play. The physx game installer did work.

Wine version tested is 1.9.7 on a x64 VM manually created with playonlinux.
To install a custom version of Wine with playonlinux go to "top menu" -> tools -> "Manage Wine Versions" -> select x86 or x64 as per your needs and proceed with the desired version.

To edit the installed libraries, wine settings and versions of an existing VM for to "Configure" on the second bar menu in playonglinux.

To create teh desired custom VM go to: "Install" on the second bar menu and navigate to the lower left corner to "Install a non-listed program" - > create a new VM and checkmark "Use another version of wine" and "install some libraries" - proceed as described above.

When closing the game you often receive a message that the game has crashed which is bogus as you just closed it :)

This should work for most applications - as there are many settings as the wine version and libraries working together its a tricky territory - i fiddled it by just trying out - in the end i would have installed a windows dualboot with ubuntu in the same amount of time.

The OS was Kubuntu 15.10 and playonlinux from the repositories.